# Share an external module between lazy loaded modules in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular2-modules, ng-modules

My app has components that use a heavy-weight external package (ag-grid, about 1MB) that is provided as an angular2 module (`AgGridModule`). I would like to load this package only when the components using it are required, so my `ContentModule` and all of its submodules are lazy-loaded. The whole structure looks like this:

[image]

However, when I import `AgGridModule` into both `Submodule1` and `Submodule3`, it ends up being included in compiled JS twice, making both 1.chunk.js and 3.chunk.js large. I tried importing it into `ContentModule`, but then the submodules do not recognize the components that are included in `AgGridModule`, even if I list them in the `exports` property of `ContentModule`.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ContentRoutingModule,
    SomeOtherModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([])
  ],
  exports: [
    // this is the component from AgGridModule that I use
    AgGridNg2
  ]
})
export class ContentModule { }
```

Is there a way to share a module between lazy loaded modules, or to expose some components of an imported module to lazy loaded children?

UPD: Creating a shared module and importing it into submodules does not help, there are still two chunks with about 1MB each:
[image]

UPD2: I solved the problem temporarily by merging Submodule1 and Submodule3 into a single module.

Comment: You should add the entire `AgGridModule` to the exports array. You can only export declarations within your `ContentModule` or entire other modules

Comment: @PierreDuc no, exporting the entire `AgGridModule` does not solve it, the component is still not being recognized.

Comment: How do you currently generate your build? angular-cli?

Comment: @AngularFrance yes, 1.0.0-beta.26.

Comment: Have you tried writing `AgGridModule` in `imports` array of `ContentModule`? As I am implementing the same scenario and working for me. P.S. I haven't created module files for child components.

Comment: @BCoder yes, I posted the definition of my ContentModule in the question. How do you define routes to your child components, with `children` or with `loadChildren`?

Comment: I have defined routes with `children`. Like this: `{
            path: 'auth',
            component: AuthComponent,
            children : [
                {
                    path: 'dashboard',
                    component: DashboardComponent
                }
            ]
        }`

Comment: @BCoder then your submodules are eager loaded. I'd like mine to be lazy loaded.

Comment: Also it gives me error if I try to load same component or directives twice.

Comment: Yes I am using eager loading.

Comment: just for clarification (or maybe a facepalm): from your screenshot, the two chunks using the module seems to be 1 and 2, approx 1mb each. From your diagram chunks 1 and 3 should be using the module. Which one is it?

Comment: @corolla names on the screenshot are slightly different. 2.chunk.js should be 3.chunk.js and vice versa. Sorry for the confusion, but I can't easily manupulate the names of chunks.

Answer (score 7):

You need to create a `SharedAgGridModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AgGridModule.withComponents([])
  ],
  exports: [
    ContentModule,
    AgGridModule
  ]
})
export class SharedAgGridModule{}
```

Then you should import this module just for the submodules which uses AgGrid. No need to also import the `ContentModule` in those submodules, because it is exported in this module

Comment: Same as with Santanu's answer, unfortunately :( I am not importing ContentModule into submodules anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SharedModule` where you `import` as well as `export` the `AgGridModule`. You have to `export` the complete module `AgGridModule` and not just the components you use.

Then you can simply `import` the `SharedModule` in your `Submodule1` and `Submodule3`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this leads to the same result. All modules that use `SharedModule` generate chunks that include the entire ag-grid.

Comment: That means there are services inside the `AgGridModule` and they need to be added to AppModule.

Comment: But I am not using any of the services from AgGridModule. I only use one of its components.

Comment: You may not be using the services directly. The components maybe using them.

Comment: Looked it up: The module does not expose any services.

Comment: Sorry @AntonPoznyakovskiy, in that case, you have to contact the module author.

Answer (score 0):

We facing the same issue.

2 Solutions

1. Put into ShareModule import and exports it. Sub module import the
   ShareModule. Basically, ShareModule is without lazy load.
2. Merge to the same path/module lazy load together.